# A simple explanation of the Born rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-interpretations, time-evolution, born-rule

The probability that an initial quantum state $|\psi_i\rangle$ becomes the final quantum state $|\psi_f\rangle$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
P(i \rightarrow f) &=& |\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle|^2 \tag{1}\\
&=& \langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle^*\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle \\
&=& \langle\psi_i|\psi_f\rangle\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}

Equation (1) seems to show that the probability for the transition ($i\rightarrow f$) can be interpreted as the system both moving forward in time ($i\rightarrow f$) with amplitude $\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle$ and backward in time ($f\rightarrow i$) with amplitude $\langle\psi_i|\psi_f\rangle$ simultaneously.

Does this reasoning help to explain the Born rule? (Is it like the Transactional Interpretation of QM?)

I guess we must experience the macroscopic direction of time ($i\rightarrow f$) in accord with increasing entropy in an expanding universe whereas microscopically QM works both forwards and backwards in time.

**Addition**

This is an improved version of the argument including time-evolution operators.

The probability that an initial quantum state $|\psi_i\rangle$ evolves to become the final quantum state $|\psi_f\rangle$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
P_{i \rightarrow f} &=& |\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle|^2 \tag{2}\\
&=& \langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle^*\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle \\
&=& \langle\psi_i|U^\dagger_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_f\rangle\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle \\
&=& \langle\psi_i|U_{f \rightarrow i}|\psi_f\rangle\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
where $U_{i \rightarrow f}$ is the forward-time evolution operator and $U_{f \rightarrow i}=U^\dagger_{i \rightarrow f}$ is the corresponding backward-time evolution operator.

Equation (2) seems to show that the probability $P_{i\rightarrow j}$ can be interpreted as the system first evolving forwards in time and then evolving backwards in time.

Perhaps this is an example of Murray Gell-Mann's [Totalitarian Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle) that "Everything not forbidden is compulsory"? At the quantum level, below observable probabilities, there is nothing to stop time flowing both forwards and backwards.

Comment: I think all you're seeing here is that the Born rule has to be consistent with the time-reversal symmetry possessed by quantum mechanics in general. Your way of stating the Born rule also seems wrong to me. The Born rule only makes sense as a way of talking about measurements. It's not a rule for time evolution. Time evolution occurs via the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: @BenCrowell "The Born rule only makes sense as a way of talking about measurements. It's not a rule for time evolution." – this statement is what proponents of different interpretations disagree about.

Comment: You should merge the material from your new question into this one; that one was closed as a duplicate of this one (as per general Stack Exchange policy), so it's no longer possible to post answers to it.

Answer (score 2):

The Born rule is adequately expressed by the first line of the equation (1). It effectively says that the probability of transition from i to f is proportional to the overlap between the two functions- you don't need invoke the additional reasoning in order to explain it.

The transactional interpretation of QM is quite separate from the Born rule. I will post an explanation of it if I can find the time.

Answer (score 0):

The Born rule and the continuity equation are just the Noether charge conservation law. The Nöther charge of the Schrödinger equation is simply $e|\psi|^2$. The probability density is proportional to the charge density by $e$.