# A simple explanation of the Born rule (v.2)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, time-evolution, born-rule

Please post further comments or answers to [A simple explanation of the Born rule?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504633/a-simple-explanation-of-the-born-rule)

The probability that an initial quantum state $|\psi_i\rangle$ evolves to become the final quantum state $|\psi_f\rangle$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
P_{i \rightarrow f} &=& |\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle|^2 \tag{1}\\
&=& \langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle^*\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle \\
&=& \langle\psi_i|U^\dagger_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_f\rangle\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle \\
&=& \langle\psi_i|U_{f \rightarrow i}|\psi_f\rangle\langle\psi_f|U_{i \rightarrow f}|\psi_i\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
where $U_{i \rightarrow f}$ is the forward-time evolution operator and $U_{f \rightarrow i}=U^\dagger_{i \rightarrow f}$ is the corresponding backward-time evolution operator.

Equation (1) seems to show that the probability $P_{i\rightarrow j}$ can be interpreted as the system first evolving forwards in time and then evolving backwards in time.

Perhaps this is an example of Murray Gell-Mann's [Totalitarian Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle) that "Everything not forbidden is compulsory"? At the quantum level, below observable probabilities, there is nothing to stop time flowing both forwards and backwards.

Does this reasoning help to explain the Born rule?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A simple explanation of the Born rule?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/504633/)

Answer (score 2):

Your question raises a number of points which I will answer in turn.

Taking the Born rule first. If you have a wave function Ψ, say, it can always be expanded in terms of the eigenfunctions φ of some operator, Op say. To give you an inexact but simple analogy, that means you can think of Ψ as being some mixture of the various eigenfunctions φ, a certain amount of this one, a little more of that one, a tiny bit of another one, and so on. The probability that Ψ will jump to become a specific instance of the φ, say φ7, depends on how much of φ7 was present in the mixture- if Ψ contained a lot of φ7 in the mixture and a tiny bit of φ23, then there would be a high probability of Ψ jumping to become φ7 and a tiny probability of it jumping to become φ23. That is the essence of the Born rule.

Gell-Mann's totalitarian principle is another way of saying that when you represent some arbitrary Ψ as a mixture of the various eigenfunctions φ of an operator Op, every single one of the φ has to be included in the mix to get it exactly right, albeit some of the φ might be present as an extremely tiny proportion of the overall mix. Under Born's rule, therefore, Ψ could jump to become any one of the φ, albeit there would be a tiny chance of it jumping to any of the φ that were present in tiny proportions in the mix.

The separate point you raise in your question concerns the fact that the equations of quantum mechanics include a time variable t, but there is nothing in the mathematics that says that t must always increase- the equations would work just as well mathematically if t was decreasing. We tend to ignore the option to consider decreasing values of t because they seem to conflict with the overwhelming evidence that t is always increasing in reality. However, that hasn't stopped some physicists from considering the possibility that a more meaningful interpretation of QM could be formulated by including negative time- that is an interesting subject for debate, but it is not a necessary concept to introduce in order to explain Born's rule or the totalitarian principle.